# Win10 Event 534 - Disk Problems

Tags: windows-10, drivers, sata, events

i just built a new pc with a fresh win10 pro installation. but from the beginning, i'm getting lots of events 534 in the eventmanager.

```
Miniport logs an error for device(Port = 0, Path = 2, Target = 0, Lun = 0).                    
Id: 52                    
Error description: Finished I/O with error                    
Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid: {0bf7b815-b90f-e30d-b3bd-540aff0671cc}                    
Adapter Guid: {bcd5e45a-41d6-11ed-8fdb-806e6f6e6963}                    
Miniport driver name: storahci                    
VendorId: TOSHIBA                     
ProductId: MG07ACA12TE                    
SerialNumber:         ***************
DataLength: 176                    
Data: 0x02000000B000000031E01000000000001601000000000000080028050000000058425253010000009000000002000000C00000000000000000000000010000001E000000000000000000000080000000000000002D02000080724DE60F82FFFF0000000000000000B0AEE0FD0F82FFFF000000000000000020E0C9F380E5FFFF40E4C9F380E5FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FF00000000000000

PortNumber = 0
PathID = 2
TargetID = 0
LUN = 0
ClassDeviceGuid = {0bf7b815-b90f-e30d-b3bd-540aff0671cc}
AdapterGuid = {bcd5e45a-41d6-11ed-8fdb-806e6f6e6963}
MiniportName = storahci
VendorId = TOSHIBA
ProductId = MG07ACA12TE
SerialNumber = **************
BootDevice = false
DataLength = 176
Data = 02000000B000000031E01000000000001601000000000000080028050000000058425253010000009000000002000000C00000000000000000000000010000001E000000000000000000000080000000000000002D02000080724DE60F82FFFF0000000000000000B0AEE0FD0F82FFFF000000000000000020E0C9F380E5FFFF40E4C9F380E5FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FF00000000000000
Id = 52
Description = Finished I/O with error
```

i found this error for at least 5 of my 10 disks (hdd + ssd).

my hardware:
AMD B550 chipset (asus prime b550 plus) with 6x onboard-sata
--> due to the lack of AMD drivers, i'm using the windows drivers (standard AHCI controller + standard NVMe controller).
marvell 92xx sata controller with 4x sata
--> marvell drivers installed

MAYBE the errors only occur for drives attached with "standard windows drivers". i can't verify it 100% because i've installed the marvell ones just days ago. but it looks like all occurrences are now for the standard drivers only.

as there are so many drives affected, i'm excluding cables (power + sata) and suspect system drivers or some software that is interfering with those (defrag, backup tools, antivirus, ... everything with own system drivers).

***do you have an idea how i could narrow it down without blindly removing software?***

the symptoms i'm feeling besides seeing the events: when i run a VM and one disk (doesn't matter which) is very busy, the rest of the system is not very responsive - even though RAM,CPU and system disk utilization is totally fine. and i have VMs on almost all drives.

thanks and cheers,
narf

Comment: I find it highly unlikely this would be a software problem. It most certainly isn't related to standard drivers. Get new high-quality SATA cables, check the disks' SMART data.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the cables and drives all worked with my old hardware (and the same external pcie sata controller). and i find it unlikely, that now at least 5 cables are failing at the same time. there has to be a "global" problem.

Comment: Well the obvious and “global” problem is that you built a new PC. Anything could’ve broken while doing that, especially old cables!